# iOS File System SandBox

Tags: ios, swift, filesystems, alamofire, sandbox

As I understand from Apple documentation, that there is sandbox for each app , so there local storage to the app can save data and files inside it and the other apps can not access its data and files, but I tried to create file by app and retrieved file URL from it and create another app and pass the file URL to it, but the new app open this file successfully, why that happen? the other app must can not be able to open the file according to Apple documentation

**In first App:**
 I download file using Alamofire

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination =
            {
            (temporaryURL, response)in                              
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let documentsURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath, isDirectory: true)
            let tmpURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("wordFile.docx")  
            return (tmpURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
          }
 Alamofire.download(urlString, to:
            destination).responseData { response in                  
                    (response.destinationURL?.path)!
//The "response.destinationURL?.path" is: "/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A0427AC0-6D5E-4734-A550-73A8224BD54D/data/Containers/Data/Application/4126243E-E166-4311-A950-D8FF49A07991/Documents/wordFile.docx"
                })
```

**In second App:** 
 I got the file path from previous App `(response.destinationURL?.path)!`
 and pass it to webView , but the webView show file the successfully

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: @Scriptable why that happen?

Comment: Depends where the file is stored, how it is passed to another app, show some code and we can understand what you are doing

Comment: I edit my question @Scriptable